# Usage of backslash in base64 string padding "\=\="

Tags: bash

I have a file that would appear to be named a base64 encoded string that is padded with "==" when viewed in macOS Finder app. However, when I drag the file over into a shell using bash 4.4 to use with the "file" command it adds two backslashes to the file's name and shows it as "\=\=" instead of "==" for some reason.

Are these escape characters that serve some purpose or is there any further explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

In a shell, `=` has the special meaning of assigning a value to an environment variable. In some special cases this could cause the shell to use a string containing `=` in some weird way.